# Trying to compare length of each sub-list (learning about lambda and list modules)

Tags: f#

I'm trying to make a function that checks a lists sublists to see if they have equal length and returns a bool value.

```
[ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ] (return true)
[ [1;2;3]; [4;5] ] (return false)
```

I'm trying to learn about lambda's and list modules.

So far I have:

```
let isTable (lst : 'a list list) : bool = 

    List.forall (fun x -> x.Length = 2) ([ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ])
```

It says x.Length is wrong somehow.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the F# type inference does not know what is type of `x` when checking the lambda function and so it cannot check whether the object will have a member `Length`. The type inference checks your program from left to right and so it only figures out that `x` will be a list when it gets to the argument `[ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ]` later in your code.

There is a couple of ways to fix this. You can use `List.length` which is a function and not an instance member, so the inference can check that:

```
let isTable (lst : 'a list list) : bool = 
    List.forall (fun x -> List.length x = 2) [ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ]
```

A nicer alternative is to use the `|>` operator which passes the thing on the left to the function on the right, so writing `x |> f` is the same as calling `f x`. This puts the input to the left, so the inference will work:

```
let isTable (lst : 'a list list) : bool = 
    [ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ] |> List.forall (fun x -> x.Length x = 2)
```

Finally, you could also add a type annotation:

```
let isTable (lst : 'a list list) : bool = 
    List.forall (fun (x:_ list) -> x.Length = 2) [ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ]
```

Out of these three, I think the most idiomatic solution is to use `|>`, but `List.length` is also common.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
let isTable (lst: 'a list list) =
    match lst with
    | [] | [[]] -> false
    | []::t -> false
    | [_] -> true
    | h::t -> t |> List.forall(fun l -> l.Length = h.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code worked by changing x.Length to x.length!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the type inference system of F# does not **firmly** recognize `x` as being a list at the point where you want to do `x.Length`. That may seem strange because if you use Intellisense (for instance by hovering over `x`) it will tell you that it is a list, yet the compiler complains.

The reason for that is that F#'s type inference does not work as well when working with Object Oriented (OO) dot `.` notation, it does much better when using functional dot `.` notation. To differentiate between the two, the convention in F# (and .Net) is that class members (methods and properties) start with a capital letter (also known as Pascal Case) hence `x.Length`. On the other hand, functional style code (like functions in a module and/or record members) start with a lower case (known as Camel Case) like `List.length`.

Notice the difference between the 2 styles:

- OO, invoke a method: `x.Length`
- Functional, call a function: `List.length x`

If you want to use the OO style, typically the solution is to add a type annotation, which you can do in several ways:

- `fun (x:_ list) -> x.Length = 2`
- `fun x -> (x:_ list).Length = 2`

In general, it is better practice to use the functional style. But, you do not always have a choice. For instance there are many String methods that do not have a functional equivalent:

```
fun (s:string) -> s.StartsWith "Hello"
```

---

I also would like to point out that your code as stated does not really do what you want. It returns true only if all lists are of length 2, not if all of them are the same length.

kagetoki's solution works and also demonstrates the use of pattern matching for lists.

Here is a simplified version:

```
let isTable lst =
    match lst with
    | h::t -> t |> List.forall(fun (l:_ list) -> l.Length = h.Length)
    | _    -> true
```

Notice that by stating that `l` is a list, it already knows that `h` is also a list.

Finally, just for fun, a super compact (but obscure) version :

```
let isTable =
    function
    | h::t -> t |> List.forall (List.length >> (=) h.Length)
    | _    -> true
```